# How do you retrieve the directory of an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Newbie question...

If I have a file that is in the root of the web app.   How do I programmaticaly query the path of that file?  ie, what directory it is in?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath( "~/filename.ext" );
```

will give you the physical (disk) path, which you would use with System.IO methods and such.

```
System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute( "~/filename.ext" );
```

will give you the "absolute" virtual path.  This won't be the full url, but isn't necessarily the root of the domain, either.  It could be something like

```
/admin/filename.ext
```

if the application is rooted in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

was close to what I was wanting.....  except that didn't seem to compile or wasn't valid in the context I was calling it.

However I found what I needed with System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath

Comment: Ah.  That should be equivalent to HttpServerUtility.MapPath( "~" )

Comment: If I use that, I get...
Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(string)'

Comment: That's odd.  Where are you calling it from?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in your ASPX markup you can break out to C# and use the ResolveUrl method like so:

```
<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/PathFromRoot/YourFile.pdf") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but I found it while searching for a similar answer. Unless the API has changed, the reason why harpo's answer isn't working is because `MapPath` is an instance method, not a static method. But fear not--there's an instance of `HttpServerUtility` present in each instance of `Controller`--the `Server` property. So in your case, if you're within a controller (or, I suspect, a view):

```
var appRoot = Server.MapPath("~/");
```

That should do the trick!